# MassTransit w/ RabbitMQ - declaring a durable exchange?

Tags: masstransit

By default, it appears MassTransit is using transient exchanges. I see there is a durable switch in both the DeclareExchange and BindQueue methods here:

https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit/blob/217d51b9d6ea19d5b01904dcceb7bacd399ace67/src/Transports/MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq/RabbitMqConnection.cs

I hoping this would be somewhat easy... Similar to EasyNetQ, where you can access the advanced bus properties, toggle the durable flag, and you are done...

I am not, however, finding where you can actually access the RabbitMqConnection object in the bus configurations, and call these methods.

Anyone happen to have an example of how to use the DeclareExchange method?

Update: The default behavior is in fact durable. The issue was due to an unsubscribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All exchanges and queues are durable by default, including any bindings between exchanges.

The only non-durable exchanges are those that are bound to publish events that are private classes, those are declared as temporary to avoid cluttering the virtual host with a bunch of internal/private class names and bindings once the connection is closed.

The only other way is if the address URI includes:

```
?temporary=true
```

In which case, it will declare it as temporary. This is often used when a temporary queue/exchange/binding is required for a transient consumer that goes away once the process is exited.

Comment: Thanks, will take a closer look Monday, although I do not recall any private classes. The code is a windows service. We stop the service, the exchange disappears. We have not seen this behavior with other rabbit apis.

Comment: May also help to show some configuration/consumer subscription code, as you can unsubscribe, which may remove the binding if the subscription is not permanent.

Comment: The behaviour of internal classes being published as non-durable just caused me some headache, because when in development process changing class from internal to public and then deploying two parts of application each at other time means that one wants the queue to be durable and other not, which is really weird and not really obvious.

Comment: I could see that being confusing. And also why using interfaces only for message contracts is such a strong recommendation.